# How restrict Tableau to view some tables from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I am both new to Tableau and PostgreSQL and here's my problem.

I already created different user in Postgres, I tried to explore **GRANT** and **REVOKE** command in order to restrict certain user to access a certain table. However, in my Tableau desktop, whenever I connect to Postgres using any user account the Tableau still show's all the table I want to hide to that user. What I want for example is that user1 can only view/import table1 and table2 while user2 can only view/import table2 and table3.

I don't know what I missed, any help will be appreciated.

OS: pure windows environment.

Comment: If you log on to the PostgreSQL database with user1 via Pgadmin, can you confirm that only table1 and table2 are visible?

Answer (score 2):

Just because a table name is listed in the Tableau connection panel when you specify your data connection, does not mean that a particular user has select access to the table.

If you revoke select access to a PostGres table, then connect to PostGres via Tableau (or any other tool), then you wont't be able to select any data from that table. If you use that same Tableau connection, but use a Postgres account that does have select access to the table, then you'll be able to select data.

Comment: Yes sir, though user1 can't access table3 but it is still visible to that user, causing a little bit confusion in user-end. Knowing we have hundreds of tables and views I think the best way to make it simple is to show only what table and field were that's only for that user. tnx

Comment: @user2530448 The best way to suggest a new feature to Tableau is to add it to their ideas page http://community.tableausoftware.com/community/ideas

Answer (score 1):

[Based on this link](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/PgAdmin-browses-all-tables-even-those-not-allowed-td2196396.html#none), the reported behaviour is related to PostgreSQL and by design, and thus not a Tableau issue.

One of the suggested workarounds would be to set up a [per-user schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html), but this would be a significant overhead if there are a large number of users.

Comment: sounds intersting, but does it means i need to replicate specific table to a new schema created for specific group of users? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's accurate to say that Tableau has no control over what tables to list from a Postgres database.

When Tableau connects this is what is executed in Postgres:

```
select relname, nspname, relkind 
from pg_catalog.pg_class c, 
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n 
where relkind in ('r', 'v') 
and nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast', 'pg_temp_1') 
and n.oid = relnamespace 
order by nspname, relname
```

Seems to me like there ought to be a way to edit this.

Edit: I've since discovered that this query is issued in the postgres driver. Just modify it and recompile the driver and you are good to go.